# Web design practices to minimize browser refresh

Tags: html, css, javascript

The design of our website is such that whenever we make some changes in CSS & JavaScript files we require the user to clear the browser cache and get the latest version of these files from the server. This is highly undesirable from the user perspective and I don't see well designed websites out there having this issue.

Are there any **website design best practices** that can be followed to minimize this issue?  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Set the HTTP headers controlling chasing appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I would say that I see these kind of pop up a lot.
The example I'm showing here is an example from sympli.io, everytime when I upload a new version of design it shows this on the top of the webpage so that I can be notified. I can't say if this is a good solution or not but hey lets collect another example.

Answer (score 0):

Web WhatsApp use a message like the one below, asking for user update.

[image: Whatsapp message]

Also you can try version or css/javascript files, you could read more here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671168/why-adding-version-number-to-css-file-path
https://www.impressivewebs.com/force-browser-newest-stylesheet/